# React typescript: JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Пытаюсь составить следующий компонент:

```
import { ReactPropTypes, Suspense, Component } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";


const Loadable = (Component: Component) => (props: ReactPropTypes) => {
    
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={ <Loader /> }>
            <Component {...props}/>
        </Suspense>
    )
}

export default Loadable;
```

получаю ошибку:

```
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
     7 |     return (
     8 |         <Suspense fallback={ <Loader /> }>
  >  9 |             <Component {...props}/>
       |              ^^^^^^^^^
    10 |         </Suspense>
    11 |     )
    12 | }
```

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно в данном случае описать компонент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { ReactPropTypes, Suspense, ComponentType } from "react";
import Loader from "./Loader";


const Loadable = (Component: ComponentType<ReactPropTypes>) => (props: ReactPropTypes) => {

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={ <Loader /> }>
      <Component {...props}/>
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default Loadable;
```